# Compositions with Restricted Domain.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

[image]

Hey Guys! How do you do this problem. There is no overlapping domain for f(x) and g(f(x)).
Detailed explanation as to how to do the problem will be preferred!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x) = 5x + 20,~x \leq 10$, one restriction on your domain is $x \leq 10$.

Since $g(x) = (x + 1)^2,~x \geq 0$, another restriction on your domain is that the quantity you substitute for $x$ satisfies $x \geq 0$.

Since

$$g(f(x)) = g(5x + 20) = ((5x + 20) + 1)^2$$

the quantity you substitute for $x$ is $5x + 20$.  Hence, $5x + 20 \geq 0$.  Thus, your domain is the intersection of the solution sets to the inequalities $x \leq 10$ and $5x + 20 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for $x$'such that $x\leq 10$ and $f(x)\geq 0$ (which is needed for decomposition).
after you find the domain of $x$ you can just subtitute $x$ in $g(x)$ with $f(x)$:

$g(f(x)) = (f(x)+1)^2 = ((5x+20)+1)^2 = (5x+21)^2$